# Can I create or edit a track in local multiplayer?

Tags: little-big-planet-karting

In *LittleBigPlanet Karting*, is it possible for two people (on one PS3) to create/edit a track together in co-op multiplayer? I have been unable to find a way.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, It's not possible to create a LBPK track in multiplayer. You can, however, sit down with your friend and take turns making the level :)

Hope this helps!